# post data to aspx page and return json object

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am trying to get data values from page without `WebMethod`, and trying to response a json object. How can I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function foo() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'foo.aspx?CalendarUC=Update',
                data: "{ 'x': '5', 'y': '6'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="foo()">click</a>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["CalendarUC"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.Params["CalendarUC"] == "Update")
            {
                var x = Request.Params["x"];
                var y = Request.Params["y"];

                //do stuff

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                Response.Write(new {result = true, message = "Hello" });
                Response.End();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to access a non ```WebMethod``` function??

Comment: yes I will use backend code in User Control, as you know User Controls can't be triggered. so I will post data to aspx page and create a method in User Control. Voilà

Answer (score 1):

You coded it right. The ajax part is correct. 
The c# part is well done also, but you just forgot to serialize your returning object like this:

```
      var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { result = true, message = "Hello" });
```

So your `Page_Load` method should look something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["CalendarUC"] != null && Request["CalendarUC"] == "Update")
        {
            var x = Request["x"];
            var y = Request["y"];

            //do stuff
            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { result = true, message = "Hello" });
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response.Write(ser);               
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

To convert any object or object list into JSON, we have to use the function JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

The below code demonstrates the use of JSON in an ASP.NET environment:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JSONFromCS
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e1)
        {
            List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.Name = "Minal";
            e.Age = 24;

            eList.Add(e);

            e = new Employee();
            e.Name = "Santosh";
            e.Age = 24;

            eList.Add(e);

            string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList, Formatting.Indented);

            string script = "var employeeList = {\"Employee\": " + ans+"};";
            script += "for(i = 0;i<employeeList.Employee.length;i++)";
            script += "{";
            script += "alert ('Name : ='+employeeList.Employee[i].Name+' 
            Age : = '+employeeList.Employee[i].Age);";
            script += "}";

            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "JSON", script, true);
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;
    }
}
```

After running this program, you will get two alerts

In the above example, we have created a list of Employee object and passed it to function "JsonConvert.SerializeObject". This function (JSON library) will convert the object list into JSON format. The actual format of JSON can be viewed in the below code snippet:

```
{ "Maths" : [ {"Name"     : "Minal",        // First element
                             "Marks"     : 84,
                             "age"       : 23 },
                             {
                             "Name"      : "Santosh",    // Second element
                             "Marks"     : 91,
                             "age"       : 24 }
                           ],                       
              "Science" :  [ 
                             {
                             "Name"      : "Sahoo",     // First Element
                             "Marks"     : 74,
                             "age"       : 27 }, 
                             {                           
                             "Name"      : "Santosh",    // Second Element
                             "Marks"     : 78,
                             "age"       : 41 }
                           ] 
            }
```

Syntax:

{} - acts as 'containers'

[] - holds arrays

: - Names and values are separated by a colon

, - Array elements are separated by commas

This code is meant for intermediate programmers, who want to use C# 2.0 to create JSON and use in ASPX pages.

You can create JSON from JavaScript end, but what would you do to convert the list of object into equivalent JSON string from C#. That's why I have written this article.

In C# 3.5, there is an inbuilt class used to create JSON named JavaScriptSerializer.

The following code demonstrates how to use that class to convert into JSON in C#3.5.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
return serializer.Serialize(YOURLIST);
```

So, try to create a List of arrays with Questions and then serialize this list into JSON

Comment: I can't see how this related to my question